# Как сворачивать/разворачивать текст используя только текст без тегов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть 3 текстовых поля в столбиках (созданные с помощью шорткодов темы wordpress), хочу сделать сворачивание/разворачивание текста в месте разрыва по клику на троеточиях в зависимости от объема текста, но проблема в том, что ни классы, ни теги типа `div` и `span` не пропускают шорткоды темы (столбики) за исключением простейших `p`, `br`, `strong`. Как это можно сделать? Можно допустить, что все столбики в свернутом размере будут одинаковой высоты. [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/430/)

```css
.row > div {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-xs-4"><p>Текст текст...текст текст</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><p>Текст текст...текст текст</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><p>Текст текст...текст текст</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит `span не пропускают столбики`?

Comment: @Jean-Claude в смысле шорткод темы на которых столбики построены

Comment: пришел к такому ответу, но мне нужно реагирование по отдельности https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/430/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так, например

```js
$(function(){
 $('.col-xs-4 p').each(function(index, el) {
  $(this).addClass('native').hide();
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.substr(0,30) + ' <strong>...</strong> ' + text.slice(-30);
  $(this).after('<p class="after">' + text + '</p>');
 });

 $('.col-xs-4 strong').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.col-xs-4').find('p.native').show().end().find('p.after').hide();
  
  //высота
  var h = 0;
  $('.col-xs-4').each(function() {
   if ($(this).height() > h) {
    h = $(this).height();
   }
  });

  $('.col-xs-4').height(h);

 });
});
```

```css
  .row > div {
   background: lightgrey;
   border: 1px solid grey;
  }

  strong:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='row'>
 <div class="col-xs-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt porro, voluptas pariatur fugiat magni laborum, ea exercitationem at debitis in laboriosam totam modi ex iste earum. Nulla, dolores sed.</p></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur ratione quae dicta, excepturi quos, facilis odio illum in eveniet rem. Eum pariatur quam dolore facere temporibus unde molestias animi provident.</p></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil dignissimos animi ipsam voluptates facere vel tempore optio, ullam reiciendis nam excepturi a accusamus porro voluptatem minus. Officia perspiciatis nam commodi.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: единственно, что список раскрывается однократно, а скрывается/закрывается